# Fix for scrollbar jumping with margin-auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to fix the scrollbar jumping issue with javascript (non-jQuery). I've found code which finds out if the scrollbar is visible or not. I can't seem to figure out how to somehow stop it from jumping. I cannot use `overflow-y: scroll;` as it spoils the design.

**I do not want to use anybody elses librarys.**

I was thinking of inserting an invisible div with the same width as my scrollbar to the left side so it would center the middle div, but it didn't work as it screws up the `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right:auto`.

This problem is driving me crazy!

html:

```
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="info"></div>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
  herro<br>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background:lightblue;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

js:

```
(function (window, document) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function resized() {
        var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
        var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var hasVerticalScrollbar = scrollHeight > clientHeight;
        if (hasVerticalScrollbar) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "scrollbar";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "!scrollbar";
        }
    });

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = "hacky-scrollbar-resize-listener";
    iframe.style.cssText = 'height: 0; background-color: transparent; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%;';

    iframe.onload = function () {
        iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            try {
                var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
                evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
                window.dispatchEvent(evt);
            } catch (e) {}
        });
    };

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})(window, document);
```

Comment: as you described, since you can detect if the scrollbar is shown or not, you may add `padding-left` to the `body` *or* `html` whenever the scrollbar is shown. but I doubt this will play seamlessly

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Yea I thought of that. However the header needs to be 100% width of the screen so :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Made a wrapper div which the middle div sits inside. Then I adjust the wrappers margin-left property when the scrollbar appears/disappears.

http://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/rxGRXR

html:

```
<div class="header">header</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="info"></div>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
    herro<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background:lightblue;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

js:

```
(function (window, document) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function resized() {
        var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
        var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var hasVerticalScrollbar = scrollHeight > clientHeight;
        if (hasVerticalScrollbar) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "scrollbar";
            document.getElementById('wrapper').style.marginLeft = '15px';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "!scrollbar";
            document.getElementById('wrapper').style.marginLeft = '0px';
        }
    });

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = "hacky-scrollbar-resize-listener";
    iframe.style.cssText = 'height: 0; background-color: transparent; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%;';

    iframe.onload = function () {
        iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            try {
                var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
                evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
                window.dispatchEvent(evt);
            } catch (e) {}
        });
    };

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})(window, document);
```